# How Did I get a solution for Joomla K2 Image problem HASH

Tags: bash, hash, joomla, imagemagick, k2

I've recently had to get a solution to move a corrupted Joomla site, but K2 items was a big problem because images where HMTL inserted, I mean not using HASH K2 method.

Hundred of images have to be inserted into its posts, so I build up a bash to get it done perfectly !!

'Convert' command comes from ImageMagick package

Create script into your K2 media image directory

usually : /var/www/html/media/k2/items/cache/

All my images are JPG so ..

Run bash using --->  for x in *.jpg ; do . k2.img.sh $x ; done

script get every file name without '.jpg', get its HASH , cut final trash , then CONVERT generate several image version acording K2 size rules of each one, and so on for every JPG file

Hope be useful

### FER

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Trabajando : ' $1

a=Image${1/.jpg/}

hash="$(echo -n "$a" | md5sum )"
echo 'Este es hash : '$hash

xxx=${hash/  -/}
echo 'Item / Hash : '  $1   $xxx.jpg

convert "$1" -resize 100 "$xxx"_XS.jpg
convert "$1" -resize 200 "$xxx"_S.jpg
convert "$1" -resize 400 "$xxx"_M.jpg
convert "$1" -resize 600 "$xxx"_L.jpg
convert "$1" -resize 900 "$xxx"_XL.jpg
convert "$1" -resize 300 "$xxx"_Generic.jpg
```